# Laravel 4 Users editing others information

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am having issues with Laravel 4. When a user logs in, they are able to create or edit a saved form called a "Project". I need to be able to make it where a user can only edit the forms "projects" that they created.  Currently, anyone can edit anyone elses project by changing the project id in the url.

**Example:** `projects/3/edit` edits the project with an id of 3

I tried using the following code but it returns an error "Trying to get property of non-object" but project is an object. Any advice is much appreciated.

### filter.php

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});

Route::filter('auth.project', function($route, $request)
{
    if($route->parameter('project')->user_id !== Auth::user()->id)
    {
        return Redirect::route('/')->with('error','sorry, you can only access projects that you created');
    }

    return Redirect::route('/');
});


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});
```

### routes.php

```
    Route::get('/projects/{projects}/edit','ProjectsController@edit',  ['before' => 'auth.project']);
```

Comment: You miss to close `}` in your filter.php?

Comment: I believe that everything is closed correctly. I'll add the entire filter.php to my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this `filter`:

```
Route::filter('auth.project', function($route, $request)
{
    if($route->parameter('project')->user_id !== Auth::user()->id)
    {
        return Redirect::route('/')->with('error','sorry, you can only access projects that you created');
    }

    return Redirect::route('/');
});
```

Here `if($route->parameter('project')->user_id !== Auth::user()->id)` is not right because the first thing is that, your route is declared as given below:

```
// This is not right
Route::get('/projects/{projects}/edit','ProjectsController@edit',  ['before' => 'auth.project']);
```

Try this:

```
Route::get('/projects/{projects}/edit', ['before' => 'auth.project', 'uses' => 'AuthorsController@edit']);
```

Also, the parameter is `projects` not `project` but you are using `project` in your filter and then, the second problem is that, you are trying to get property of `non-object` because `$route->parameter('project')` returns `null` and even if you use `projects` then it may return the `3` but still that will throw an error because `3` is not an object. You need to grab that `Project` whose `id` is `3` or you may use a route model binding. So, if you use something like this:

```
$project = Project::find($route->parameter('projects')); // Assumed that 3 is id
if($project->user_id !== Auth::user()->id) {
    //...
}
```

Also you may use a [route model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding) like this:

```
Route::model('projects', 'Project'); // Project Model must be existed
Route::get('/projects/{projects}/edit', ['before' => 'auth.project', 'uses' => 'AuthorsController@edit']);
```

Then in your `edit` method:

```
public function edit(Project $project)
{
    // $project is an Eloquent Object, will be injected automatically...
});
```

Comment: OK, I went ahead and made the changes to both my route and my filters as suggested and it is working now. I am going to check out and learn more about the Route Model Binding as well.

I sometimes get confused when to use "projects" vs "project".

Answer (score 0):

Well, just looking at what you've posted here, I see a couple issues.

First, you named your parameter `projects` in your route and try to access `project` in your filter, which is non-existent.

Second, `$route` is of type `Illuminate\Routing\Route` which has a method called `getParameter`, not `parameter`. More can be found in the documentation linked [here](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.Route.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is a `parameter` method available in `Route` class.